# Get all Friends using FQL

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My code is here

```
query = "SELECT uid FROM USER " +
        "WHERE uid IN (" +
        "  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = #{fb_user_id}" +
        ")"

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=#{query}&access_token=#{fb_access_token}"
escape_url = URI::escape(url)
uri = URI.parse(escape_url)

# Configure http settings to hit a url.
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
# extract the response body.
response = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

It return only

> 10 friends

I want to extract **all friend** how can i do this 
 **Any other way to extract all friends list**
Please some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using a v1.0 application that API call will only return friends using the application.

> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

This applies to the FQL friend table as well.